# Run Stored Procedure from Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, stored-procedures, azure-devops

I'm working on an Azure DevOps repository from Visual Studio 2017. Every time I implement any change and need to unit test I need to run a sequence of stored procedures that are in this same repository.

These Stored Procedures are like `CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[Table] ...` so once they already exist in the DB, I need to manually change from `CREATE` to `ALTER` and then run one by one

I would like to have a script to identify which procedures where modified  in my branch and based on a condition, change (temporarily) the procedures from `CREATE` to `ALTER` and execute them in sequence in the DB

How can I automate this? My DB is already set up in Visual Studio

Comment: Are you using anything to manage spinning up and tearing down your test infrastructure, such as puppet or teraform?  They have mechanism to test what already exists and what does not.  If you're just rolling your own script, why not just use the `CREATE OR ALTER [Schema].[Object]` syntax?  *(But note, if you're altering a TABLE, just taking the CREATE statement and changing one word to ALTER will **not** work.)*

Comment: Because it is not my own code. It is like that in master and I don't want to change it as it is used to deploy to other environments

Comment: Can you confirm that you are already using a _database project_ in Visual Studio? You can generate change scripts and deploy those. It only deploys changed code. This can be automated in Azure DevOps but I'm unsure from your description exactly what you're trying to solve.

Comment: You can also add post deployment scripts but again I'm unsure what you're trying to do

Comment: I don't think it's a database project. It is an Azure DevOps Repo so there is database, databricks notebooks, Datafactory, and several resources. We already have a CI/CD pipeline to deploy to environments. What I'm looking for is some way to automatize when developing and avoid to manually run storage procedures that where changed